# Executing linux time command inside python

Tags: python, linux, shell, time, subprocess

I want to calculate the time taken to execute a c program inside a python script. I used os.system() function for this.

```
os.system("{ time ./test.out < inp;} > out 2> exe_time")
```

- test.out is my c executable
- inp contains input for c
- out stores the output of c program
- exe_time stores the execution time of the program.

The result I get in exe_time is something like this

> 0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1416maxresident)k 0inputs+8outputs (0major+65minor)pagefaults 0swaps

But when I execute { time ./test.out < inp;} > out 2> exe_time in terminal I get in the exe_time file

> real    0m0.001s
>   user    0m0.000s
>   sys     0m0.000s

How do I get the second version of output by using python?

Comment: What do you get from `sh -c '{ time ./test.out < inp;} > out 2> exe_time'` at your interactive shell? That's what `system()` is doing: It invokes `/bin/sh`, not bash or zsh or whatever your interactive shell is.

Comment: If you want the implementation of `time` provided by bash, don't use `system()`; instead use something like `subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '{ time ./test.out < inp;} > out 2> exe_time'])` to specify bash *explicitly*.

Comment: ...or, more safely (if your filenames or arguments are not constant): `subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'in=$1; shift; out=$1; shift; err=$1; shift; { time "$@" < "$in";} > "$out" 2> "$err"', '_', 'inp', 'out', 'exe_time', './test.out'])` to pass parameters out-of-band from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke your code with `bash`, not `/bin/sh` (as is default for `system()`):

```
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '{ time ./test.out < inp;} > out 2> exe_time'])
```

Note however that the above code is not safe to parameterize to work with arbitrary filenames. A better-practices implementation might instead look like:

```
o, e = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'time "$@" 2>&1', '_', './test.out'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

print("Output from command is:")
sys.stdout.write(o + "\n")
print("Output from time is:")
sys.stdout.write(e + "\n")
```

Note:

- We're explicitly invoking `bash`, and thus ensuring that its built-implementation of `time` is used.
- Passing arguments out-of-band from the shell script makes it safe to pass arbitrary arguments to the script being run without worrying about whether those arguments contain attempted shell injection attacks.
- Redirecting `2>&1` within the shell script ensures that any stderr written by `test.out` is joined with other output, not mixed in with the output from the `time` command.
- If we *did* want to redirect output to files, the better-practice approach would be to do that from Python, as with `stdout=open('out', 'w'), stderr=open('exe_time', 'w')`.

Comment: What does '_' represent in the subprocess command? Suppose if I have to read inp from file, in the subprocess command can I give './test.out < inp_file'?

Comment: @Perseus14, the `_` becomes `$0`; as such, it's a placeholder for a value we don't care about, since `"$@"` only expands to `$1` and onward. `stdin=open('inp_file', 'r')` to read from a file, or `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and pass your data as an argument to `communicate()`.

Comment: Sorry @Charles, I am not getting the command. Is this the one o, e = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'time "$@" 2>&1', '_', './test.out'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin= subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(open("inp_file".'r').readline())

Comment: If you're reading from a file, then just use `subprocess.Popen([...], stdin=open('inp_file', 'r'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()`. I suggested `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` with the explicit argument to `communicate()` to provide an explicit alternative if you thought the file was mandatory, as opposed to if its use is actually sensible for your use case. (And btw, it would just be `read()`, not `readline`, if you wanted to pass the whole file through).

Comment: Thanks @Charles!! Everything's working well. (Yes you are right read() is appropriate but my file only contains one line, so it's alright)

Answer (score 1):

`os.system()` uses `/bin/sh`. Bash has its own `time` builtin that it uses instead of the `time` binary:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ls /asd
ls: /asd: No such file or directory
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
$ time ls /asd
ls: /asd: No such file or directory

real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.013s
```

If you want to see how long it takes for a command to be executed, just use `subprocess`:

```
import time
import subprocess

with open('inp', 'rb') as input_file:
    with open('out', 'wb') as output_file:
        start = time.time()
        subprocess.call(['./test.out'], stdin=input_file, stdout=output_file)
        runtime = time.time() - start
```

Comment: If the OP just wants wall-clock time, the latter approach (comparing `time.time()` from Python) is definitely the Right Thing. If they care about the user/system/wall-clock split, it might not quite suffice.